# Bounded solutions of homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that all eigenvalues of $A$ are of non-negative real part, and all generalized eigenvectors of $A$ are eigenvectors. Show that all solution of $X'=AX$ are bounded.

I know that if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are of negative real part then all solutions of $X'=AX$ are bounded. But I do not know how to use the other assumption "all generalized eigenvectors of $A$ are eigenvectors". Any hint?

Comment: Does it mean the operator $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes. I think $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if all generalized eigevectors are eigenvectors.

Comment: Good. Then basically problem solved. Just expand $X$ into the eigenbasis of $A$. Every eigenbasis then has to decay (or decay while oscillating).